# Gmail block from even spam

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, spam-prevention, blacklist

How can I block a certain 'email address' from reaching my spam folder in gmail.

I have blocked the email already all mails gets sent to spam but now I want too block it from spam too.

Edit: I am thinking of creating a folder "never to be seen" and having all correspondance from said email to this folder.

Answer (score 2):

> Edit: I am thinking of creating a folder "never to be seen" and having
>   all correspondance from said email to this folder.

You want to create a filter.

1. find a message from this email address and select it.
2. Click the "More" button and Select "filter messages like these"
3. In the window that pops up, in the bottom right corner click "Create Filter with this search"
4. In the new window that pops up select:

   - skip the inbox
   - apply the label
   - Never send to spam
5. when you select "apply the label" you must select an existing label or create one.
6. Optional: you can click on the option to apply filter to X matching conversations.
7. Click "Create filter"

Now the new label will be applied to that message and all new messages. They will not go to spam, they won't appear on the front page.

I am not sure it will catch emails already in spam. I didn't test it for that.

Answer (score 0):

Block an email address
When you block a sender, your messages are moved to the Spam folder.

Open Gmail on a computer.
Open the message.
At the top right, click the down arrow Down arrow.
Click Lock [sender].
If you block someone by mistake, you can unlock it by following the same steps